# sed words with several quotation marks

Tags: linux, sed

I spent already 3 hrs of my time trying to solve this but I'm not Linux tech but this is so annoying.

I need to find a piece of text in a file test.txt

```
"cPHulk":{"BruteForce":3,"Login":3,"*":3}
```

and change it for:

```
"cPHulk":{"BruteForce":1,"Login":1,"*":1}
```

Could you please help me and tell me how would the correct sed command looks like.

Many thanks for your help

EDIT: I've tried this:

```
sed -e  "s/\"cPHulk\":{\"BruteForce\":3,\"Login\":3,\"*\":3}/\"cPHulk\":{\"BruteForce\":1,\"Login\":1,\"*\":1}" /root/test.txt
```

But unfortunately I'm getting error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 45: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: add at least one of the commands you tried to question... the `*` in search string has to be escaped... use `\*`

Comment: Updated with what I tried

Comment: is it json file? If so, can you post it?

Comment: @LukeJ you get the error because you missed `/` at end... syntax is `s/regexp/replacement/flags` and need to use `\*` instead of `*` in `regexp` portion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
foo
"cPHulk":{"BruteForce":3,"Login":3,"*":3}
bar

$ sed 's/"cPHulk":{"BruteForce":3,"Login":3,"\*":3}/"cPHulk":{"BruteForce":1,"Login":1,"*":1}/' ip.txt 
foo
"cPHulk":{"BruteForce":1,"Login":1,"*":1}
bar
```

Use single quotes, only `*` needs to be escaped. See [Overview of basic regular expression syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-syntax)